# Chrome transform matrix iframe rendering glitch

Tags: css, google-chrome, iframe, transform

I have a weird rendering glitch on a webpage in google chrome. I reproduced it under Mac Chrome, and Chrome under a parrallels virtual machine in windows.

It's supposed to be a simple draggable div. But, when you drag it around, it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8vn4.jpg

The situation is pretty unusual; it's a container div with a css transform matrix, containing an iframe, with a draggable div.

I created a demo. Just drag the div around: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cjq39w82mghuze2/bug.7z?dl=0

Any idea what causes this?

[edit]

I still have no idea. But: updating the transform matrix of the parent element (in my case, I was using fit.js, and call watching.trigger()) forces a redraw. So, that might be a useful workaround that helps people. :)

Answer (score 1):

I found an actual fix that is not stupid and half-working like my earlier attempt.

```
iframe {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

To clarify, to any iframe in which you have this happening, apply the above CSS.

No more glitches. Stupid, I have no idea why it worked, but I just tried random things, and then this worked. I'm guessing it enables some kind of different rendering flow that avoids this bug, whatever it is.

Comment: This solution works.